# Invalid prop/context `relay`

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, relayjs, react-router-relay

I did a fresh `npm install` and suddenly am getting the following error

```
warning.js?8a56:44 Warning: Failed context type: Invalid prop/context relay supplied to Relay(FilesPage), expected undefined to be an object conforming to the RelayEnvironment interface.
    in Relay(FilesPage) (created by RouterContext)
    in div (created by Row)
    in Row (created by Column)
    in Column (created by App)
    in div (created by StyleRoot)
    in StyleRoot (created by App)
    in Provider (created by App)
    in App (created by AppWithStore)
    in Provider (created by AppWithStore)
    in AppWithStore (created by RouterContext)
    in RouterContext (created by Router)
    in Router (created by Root)
    in Root
```

This is my root container

```
const Root = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router
      history={browserHistory}
      routes={routes}
      onReadyStateChange={readyState => {
        console.log(99, readyState)
        if (!readyState.done) store.dispatch(toggleLoading(true))
        else store.dispatch(toggleLoading(false))
      }}
      render={applyRouterMiddleware(useRelay)}
      environment={Relay.Store}
    />
  </Provider>
)
```

Comment: What's your relay version in your `package.json` file? Is it `~` or `^`?

Comment: I didn't notice this closed issue until now https://github.com/relay-tools/react-router-relay/issues/189 trying this out and will update my question